# Stop UILocalNotification Sound on slide to view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uilocalnotification

In my alarm app, I am scheduling an alarm on some time.

With the app in foreground I lock my iPhone (iOS7, I haven't tried with iOS6).

Now when the notification sound starts, I view the local notification by using the "Slide to view" on my lock screen, and when the app opens, I also play the sound using `AVAudioPlayer`.

So the problem is notification sound continuously ringing until 30.0 seconds.

Is this iOS issue or in the code I need to integrate any method etc.?

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution for this? Because I am facing the exact same issue.

Comment: Can you post some of your code so that we can see how you are handing your AVPlayer?

Comment: Hi, I just found a work around for this ios bug - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527704/the-uilocalnotification-sound-does-not-stop-playing/24530013?noredirect=1#comment37986732_24530013

Comment: Yes, this is an iOS issue and also mention in apple developer forum: https://devforums.apple.com/message/888091#888091

Answer (score -2):

according to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24530013/3033386) SO post, this is a bug with iOS 7 where the sound doesn't stop when the user 'slides to view' if passcode lock is turned off.

possible fixes can include turning on passcode lock or using this code (taken from the linked post).

```
 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
   [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
   [session setActive:YES error:nil];
   MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    [musicPlayer setVolume:0.0f]; 
}
```

**This bug has been fixed as of iOS 8**